# Login with diferrent levels of users using PHP and SQL Server

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, authentication

I am trying to do a login for php and sql server by different `UserType` I've tried to do a login without the `UserType` and i can login. But i have no idea how to do a login based on `UserType`. Anyways, this is what i have tried :

**UserType** :

- User
- Superior
- Admin

**login_action.php** (w/o UserType)

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once 'connection.php';

$EmployeeId = $_POST['EmployeeId'];
$Password  = $_POST['Password'];

$tsql = "SELECT * FROM LOGIN WHERE EmployeeId='$EmployeeId' AND Password='$Password'";
$result = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql, $params, array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET ));

$num = sqlsrv_num_rows($result);
if($num==1){
    header('Location: user.php');
    $_SESSION['valid_user'] = true;
    $_SESSION['EmployeeId'] = $EmployeeId;
    die();}
else
    header('Location: login.php');
    die();      
?>
```

**login_action.php** (with UserType)

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once 'connection.php';

$EmployeeId = $_POST['EmployeeId'];
$Password  = $_POST['Password'];
$UserType = $_POST['UserType'];

$tsql = "SELECT * FROM LOGIN WHERE EmployeeId='$EmployeeId' AND Password='$Password' AND UserType='$UserType'";
$result = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql,$params , array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET ));

$num = sqlsrv_num_rows($result);
if($num==1){
    $_SESSION['EmployeeId']=$EmployeeId;
    $_SESSION['UserType']=$UserType;
    if($UserType=="USER")
    {
        header("Location:user.php");
    }
    else if ($UserType=="SUPERIOR")
    {
        header("Location:superior.php");
    }
    else if ($UserType=="ADMIN")
    {
        header("Location:admin.php");
    }
    else 
    die("Not a valid User Type");

    }
    else
    header('Location: login.php');
?>
```

Comment: Sidenote: Add `exit;` after all your headers.

Comment: *`" But after i edit the code, it won't let the user to login anymore."`* Isn't an accurate error description. Elaborate more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its okay, I've got it worked out. I just forgot to write this line :

```
$_SESSION['valid_user'] = true;
```

And as Fred -ii- suggested, I've added the exit(); after each of the header

Comment: *Ah,* good show ;) Plus, error reporting doesn't hurt http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php